# Transform a list of maps to a map that uses ImmutablePair with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I rewrite this old style of code to use Java 8 streams?  I know it can be done with a single line of stream code.

```
Map<String, ImmutablePair<Double, Double>> dataCache = new LinkedHashMap<>()
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, Object> rec : data) {
    String code = (String) rec.get("code");
    Double x0 = (Double) rec.get("x0");
    Double x1 = (Double) rec.get("x1");
    dataCache.put(code, new ImmutablePair<>(x0, x1));
}
```

Essentially the idea is to remap a generic list of records into a more structured hash lookup.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a single *line* of stream code:

```
Map<String, ImmutablePair<Double, Double>> dataCache = data.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(rec -> (String) rec.get("code"), rec -> new ImmutablePair<>((Double) rec.get("x0"), (Double) rec.get("x1")), (a, b) -> b, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, ImmutablePair<Double, Double>> dataCache = data.stream()
   .collect(
       Collectors.toMap(
          rec -> (String) rec.get("code"),
          rec -> new ImmutablePair<>(
              (Double) rec.get("x0"), (Double) rec.get("x1"))));
```

If you care about the map implementation, you probably want

```
Map<String, ImmutablePair<Double, Double>> dataCache = data.stream()
   .collect(
       Collectors.toMap(
          rec -> (String) rec.get("code"),
          rec -> new ImmutablePair<>(
              (Double) rec.get("x0"), (Double) rec.get("x1")),
          (p1, p2) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); },
          LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Need two more params to `toMap()` to produce a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Technically, that is not the same, since you now throw exception on duplicate key. In original code, last `put()` wins, so merge function should do that too. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43333222/5221149), which also does it in one *line*, like OP asked. ;-) Still, +1 for beating me to the punch.

Comment: @Andreas, what about this isn't one line?

Comment: It is 1 *statement*, wrapped over 8 *lines* of source code. ;-)